# Visualforce URLFOR parameter binding

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I'm trying to override the new case functionality to prepopulate certain fields depending on which recordtype the user selects. 
This is my visualforce action page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase,$ObjectType.Case,[cas5={!cs.caseType}, cas7 = {!cs.status}true)}" extensions="NewCaseOverrideExtension" >
```

And my controller:

```
public class NewCaseOverrideExtension {
    public Case cs {get; set;}
    public String subject {get; private set;}
    public String comments {get; private set;}
    public String description {get; private set;}
    public String caseOrigin {get; private set;}
    public String priority {get; private set;}
    public String accountName {get; private set;}
    public String status {get; private set;}
    public String caseType {get; private set;}
    public NewCaseOverrideExtension(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        if(cs == null) cs = new Case();
        Id recordTypeId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');
        if(recordTypeId == Schema.SobjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Animal Protection').getRecordTypeId()){
            subject = 'Test Animal Protection Subject';
            comments = 'Test Animal Protection Comments';
            description = 'Test Animal Protection Description';
            caseOrigin = 'Test Animal Protection Case Origin';
            priority = 'High';
            status = 'In Progress';
            caseType = 'Inquiry';
        }

    }
}
```

I'm having problems binding the parameters to the page, even when I include single or double quotes.

Is my approach ill conceived?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>If you look at [Valid Values for the $Action Global Variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm), `NewCase` is not listed. The correct action is `New`.</s>

Take a look at the [Visualforce Developer Guide - Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm). The syntax is `{!URLFOR(target, id, [inputs], [no override])}`, so the second parameter should definitely be `null` if you are trying to create a new record. One last problem, you are missing your closing `]` bracket (and the `,` to delimit the next parameter).

**EDIT** As noted by @[sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox), you do not need merge syntax when you are already within a merge, so you must remove all `{!...}` brackets.

Putting it all together:

> {!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase, **null**, [ cas5=cs.caseType, cas7=cs.status **],** true)}

Compare with:

> {!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase,$ObjectType.Case,[cas5= **{!** cs.caseType **}**, cas7 = **{!** cs.status **}** true)}

---

In testing this solution, I found that despite what the documentation says, `NewCase` works, while `New` doesn't. I have provided feedback that the documentation is not correct.

Comment: You don't need merge syntax for the inputs parameter, because you're already in merge syntax. `{!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase,null,[cas5=cs.caseType, cas7=cs.status], true)}`.

Comment: @sfdcfox Good catch. Shouldn't have tried it with hard coded strings.